# Manage process in Linux with C++

Tags: c++, linux

I want to write a program to kill a bad process in Linux.

The program should detect all threads and processes running in Linux. I know I should use the /proc folder but does it return all processes? And how I can kill a process in C++ from its ID?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: **[`man proc`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc)**

Answer (score 3):

If you want to kill another process in C on Linux/UNIX you should use **kill** function ([kill man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/kill) for more information) and provide as first parameter PID of the process you want to kill and **SIGKILL** constant as second parameter.

```
kill(1234, SIGKILL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to send it a [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/3/kill) signal.